# checkedlistbox item check to listbox

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I'm using this code to pass the selected item to a listbox called SelectedList. The problem is that nothing happens when I checked an item of my chekedlistbox, what can be the problem here?

```
 public void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                selectedList.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

            }
            else
            {
                selectedList.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedList.Text = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: When you debug the code is it hitting any of the Events..?

Comment: How can I know if it's debugging this events?

Comment: you add break points and Hit F5 and start running your code...

Comment: Ok, I used the breakpoint and this events are not considered.

Comment: the selectedindexchanged event its considered but the itemcheck I dont know why isn't.

Comment: Where are the items being added to your CheckListBox show more code where are you defining selectedList also...

Comment: Dude you need to know the difference between a CheckListBox and a CheckBox your code is not working because you are trying to get at a single item vs looping thru the ListItems to check the selected state I would use a case statement personally

Comment: the items are on the design of the checkboxlistbox, they're only 5 but the itemcheck event isn't working

Comment: here i will say it once again.. remove the event that you have , then double click on the checklistbox and then write you code in the         private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        } 
in order to check the items that are checked you need to create a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was the event checkedListBox1_ItemCheck was not activated in the event tab, that was the reason the compiler didn't considered it in the debugging process.